# Using C's fwrite in a for loop

Tags: c, loops, fwrite

I have searched the site and I haven't found an answer to my problem.

My program outputs an image, and I want to save to a different file, each image produced after an cycle iteration.

My code to save files is this

```
FILE *fobjecto;
if ((fobjecto = fopen ("OSEM.ima", "wb")) != NULL)                 
{   
    printf("Writing reconstructed image file"); 
    fwrite (objecto, sizeof(float), (detectorXDim)*detectorYDim*(NSlices-1), fobjecto);    
    fclose (fobjecto);     
}    
else    
    printf("Reconstructed image file could not be saved");
```

I want to add one integer variable  to the output file's name, I have tried playing with "+" and "," but I could not solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big can that number ever become?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need some formatted output operation like `sprintf` (or even better its safe twin `snprintf`):

```
char buf[512]; // something big enough to hold the filename
unsigned int counter;
FILE * fobjecto;

for (counter = 0; ; ++counter)
{
  snprintf(buf, 512, "OSEM_%04u.ima", counter);

  if ((fobjecto = fopen(buf, "wb")) != NULL) { /* ... etc. ... */ }

  // Filenames are OSEM_0000.ima, OSEM_0001.ima, etc.
}
```

Comment: 1000 is a little big for something that won't be over 20 characters.

Answer (score 5):

```
char file_name[256];

sprintf(file_name, "OSEM%4.4d.ima", iteration_count);

if (NULL!=(fobjecto=fopen(file_name, "wb")))
  // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

construct the file name before you open it:

```
char filename[256];
//...
sprintf(filename, "OSEM%08X.ima", someIntegerToAddAsHex);
if ((fobjecto = fopen (filename, "wb")) != NULL)      
//...
```